# Подчеркивание блоков по высоте

Tags: css, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap. Нужно, чтобы у всех 3х блоков было разноцветное подчеркивание, адаптированное под высоту общего контейнера.

Код:

```css
.footer__soc {
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: rgba(45, 47, 60, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container footer__soc">
  <div class="col-md-8 footer__about">
    <h3 class="soc__title">
      ФУРГОНЩИК
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__text">
      Недорогой переезд по Москве, Московской области и России
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__connect">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle">
      Для связи
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__item">+7(499)390-62-65</p>
    <p class="soc__item">Furgonshchik@gmail.com</p>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__links">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle--yellow">
      Мы в соц. сетях
    </h3>
    <a href="https://vk.com/public131662966">
      <img src="icons/vk.png" alt="" class="img-responsive soc__link">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно градиентом, например, сделать. Одну общую полоску внизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запихнуть градиент (спасибо @kizoso) в границу блока.

```css
.footer__soc {
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: rgba(45, 47, 60, .8);
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(233,96,75,1) 0%,rgba(233,96,75,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 50%,rgba(165,117,225,1) 50%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 100%) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container footer__soc">
  <div class="col-md-8 footer__about">
    <h3 class="soc__title">
      ФУРГОНЩИК
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__text">
      Недорогой переезд по Москве, Московской области и России
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__connect">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle">
      Для связи
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__item">+7(499)390-62-65</p>
    <p class="soc__item">Furgonshchik@gmail.com</p>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__links">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle--yellow">
      Мы в соц. сетях
    </h3>
    <a href="https://vk.com/public131662966">
      <img src="icons/vk.png" alt="" class="img-responsive soc__link">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить псевдоэлемент с градиентом:

```css
.footer__soc {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: rgba(45, 47, 60, .8);
}

.footer__soc:after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  background: rgb(233,96,75);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(233,96,75,1) 0%, rgba(233,96,75,1) 25%, rgba(60,186,145,1) 25%, rgba(60,186,145,1) 50%, rgba(165,117,225,1) 50%, rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%, rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%, rgba(218,161,88,1) 75%, rgba(218,161,88,1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(233,96,75,1) 0%,rgba(233,96,75,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 50%,rgba(165,117,225,1) 50%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(233,96,75,1) 0%,rgba(233,96,75,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 25%,rgba(60,186,145,1) 50%,rgba(165,117,225,1) 50%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(165,118,226,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 75%,rgba(218,161,88,1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e9604b', endColorstr='#daa158',GradientType=1 );
}
```

```html
<div class="container footer__soc">
  <div class="col-md-8 footer__about">
    <h3 class="soc__title">
      ФУРГОНЩИК
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__text">
      Недорогой переезд по Москве, Московской области и России
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__connect">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle">
      Для связи
    </h3>
    <p class="soc__item">+7(499)390-62-65</p>
    <p class="soc__item">Furgonshchik@gmail.com</p>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 footer__links">
    <h3 class="soc__subtitle--yellow">
      Мы в соц. сетях
    </h3>
    <a href="https://vk.com/public131662966">
      <img src="icons/vk.png" alt="" class="img-responsive soc__link">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте на чистоту: Фаерфокс 15-, ИЕ9-, Сафари 6- счас уже никто не поддерживает.

Comment: @sasha-omelchenko да, с границей похоже, что оптимальнее)

Comment: Это был коммент про префиксирование градиентов )